# Upgrading from Vista Home Basic to Vista Business

Tags: windows, windows-vista, license-key, upgrade

I have a PC that came with Vista Home Basic, and I now have some need for Remote Desktop, which is not included in Home Basic, so I'd like to upgrade.

Now, there is apparently some hack to get Remote Desktop working in Home Premium, and obviously, it's in Ultimate, but really, the Business Edition would be the best fit for us. Unfortunately, Windows Anytime Upgrade does not provide a path from Home Basic to Business.

My question is, if I were to buy a standalone Vista Business license, could I use it to do an upgrade from my current Home Basic installation? Would it be simply entering the new license key?

Comment: First, I suggest jumping to Windows 7 - it's an improvement over Vista. Second, I suggest spending the extra money and buying a full retail install instead of an upgrade. The retail install can be migrated to another PC if you buy/build a new machine. The upgrade will be tied to the OEM original, which is tied to the HW.

Comment: I was hoping to buy a full version, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not be simply entering the new license key.

I believe a full retail install is the only solution...
I believe you would have to boot off your Vista Business installation disc, enter the key, and choose the "Upgrade" option. (According to Microsoft support sites ([here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Upgrade-to-another-edition-of-Windows-Vista)) a clean install is NOT required.)

If you don't have the Vista Business disc... I believe Vista discs are all in one, meaning that any version of disc can install any version of Vista (depending on which product key is entered), meaning that your home basic disc can probably install Vista Business. You might want to verify this first though since I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it indeed claims an upgrade to Business is possible.